# Incorporate try except block with python code

Tags: python, linux, exception, try-except

I'm populating a spreadsheet with multiple queries that return a key and a corresponding value. Two database connections are being used in the script to return data.

The following code works perfectly if there is not an issue with the SQL statement being executed. If there is a problem with the SQL the programs exit with errors and my spreadsheet isn't populated.

If there is an error, I would like to still populate the key in the first column and have the value return '0'

Tricky part is since there are two server connections, one server might handle the SQL perfectly fine and the other might throw an exception.

Is there a way this code block can be converted to handle that?

I'm a bit of a Python newb, so delving into error handling is a bit daunting

```
# Populate the spreadsheet with data from the first set of date ranges.
row = 1
col = 0

for key, value in Queries.query_dic.iteritems():
    cur.execute(value.format(from_dateA,to_dateA))
    cur2.execute(value.format(from_dateA,to_dateA))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    rows2 = cur2.fetchall()

    # Populate metric being queried in our horizontal headers
    worksheet[index].write(row, col, key, format)
    worksheet[index + 1].write(row, col, key, format)

    # Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
    for return_count in rows:
        worksheet[index].write(row, col + 1, return_count[0], format2)

    for return_count in rows2:
        worksheet[index + 1].write(row, col + 1, return_count[0], format2)

    row += 1
```

Comment: Which statement throws error? And of which type?

Comment: Well, for example if there is bad syntax in SQL it will throw an error. I'm not sure if this occurs on the cur.execute statement or the cur.fetchall()

Answer (score 0):

To use a try-except you can do this

```
try:
    for key, value in Queries.query_dic.iteritems():
        cur.execute(value.format(from_dateA,to_dateA))
        cur2.execute(value.format(from_dateA,to_dateA))
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        rows2 = cur2.fetchall()

        # Populate metric being queried in our horizontal headers
        worksheet[index].write(row, col, key, format)
        worksheet[index + 1].write(row, col, key, format)

        # Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
        for return_count in rows:
            worksheet[index].write(row, col + 1, return_count[0], format2)

        for return_count in rows2:
            worksheet[index + 1].write(row, col + 1, return_count[0], format2)

        row += 1
except:
    # Error Handling
```

If you want to have error-specific handling, you can simply put the error after the except

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Error Handling
```

Comment: The problem here is since there are two servers that I'm connecting to, the query might be fine for one and not for the other. With this code if one server 'breaks' it will throw an exception even if the other server can handle the SQL perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found a solution that works.

```
# Print metric headers and counts for first date range.
row = 1
col = 0

for key, value in Queries.query_dic.iteritems():

    # Write the metrics headers
    worksheet[index].write(row, col, key, format)
    worksheet[index + 1].write(row, col, key, format)

    # Populate spreadsheet with count returned from query for Environment 1. 
    try:
        cur.execute(value.format(from_dateA,to_dateA))
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for return_count in rows:
            worksheet[index].write(row, col + 1, return_count[0], format2)
    # Query will fail if module doesn't exist; in this case print '0'.
    except:
        worksheet[index].write(row, col + 1, '0', format2)

    # Populate spreadsheet with count returned from query for Environment 2. 
    try:
        cur2.execute(value.format(from_dateA,to_dateA))
        rows = cur2.fetchall()
        for return_count in rows:
            worksheet[index + 1].write(row, col + 1, return_count[0], format2)
    # Query will fail if module doesn't exist; in this case print '0'.
    except:
        worksheet[index + 1].write(row, col + 1, '0', format2)

    row += 1
```